# Running Filebeat on Docker Errors Out

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, elk

I was following this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-docker.html#_run_the_filebeat_setup

```
docker run \
docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.0.0 \
setup -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:port \
-E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["https://testelk.es.us-east4.gcp.elastic-cloud.com:9243"] \
cloud -E cloud.id=cloudid \
-E cloud.auth=elastic:pass
```

I get the following error on my macOS when I run it on my terminal. Is there a way to fix it?

```
zsh: no matches found: output.elasticsearch.hosts=[https://testelk.es.us-east4.gcp.elastic-cloud.com:9243]
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in the documentation, if you are using Elastic Cloud, you need to remove the `output.elasticsearch.hosts` option and specify only the `cloud.id` and `cloud.auth`.